# How do I get the "Day of the Week" using MonthCalendar?

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I am using WinForms and I am trying to get the day of the week.

So if someone selects 2/16/2017 then I will get Thursday.

I know the DateTimePicker control can do this but I really need to  use monthCalendar

Comment: DayOfWeek is a property of DateTime

Comment: Can I convert a monthCalendar date to a DAteTimePicker object?

Comment: Just  monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.DayOfWeek  ?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, The easiest way to use `DateTime.DayOfWeek`.

```
mounthCalerndar.SelectionStart.DayOfWeek
```

Should do the work.